# google maps shows Blank page with left under corner google logo

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to add a map activity inside Android studio 
i have created a new project and added a new map activity
i have got the link inside the file :

> `google_maps_api.xml`

and then copied it at `developer.android.com` and got the Api key for my application 
i am sure of all my permissions and the `sha-1` is correct.
where is the problem ?
the file: `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="HereGoesthepackage.mymaptest11">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.barcodelibrary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Edit:**

> activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="HereGoesthePackage.mymaptest11.MapsActivity" />
```

> Mapsactivity.java:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: share you activity.

Comment: this happens only cause of problems with api keys/credentials

Comment: @HemantParmar 
See the Update

Comment: @AntonKazakov
log cat give this :
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

Comment: did you enable google map api key? check it once.

Comment: @HemantParmar
yes i just created the project and enabled the api key
and its name on developer.android.com

Comment: You should get your API key from console.developers.google.com and not developer.android.com

Comment: @rafid059
I got it from the link inside file:<b>google_maps_api.xml</b>
  https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=........
and so on

Comment: **1.** Did you copy the API key into that xml file? **2.** Is the package name correct in the console.developers.google.com project?

Comment: all these solutions have been tried before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As cleared above your code is clean and without mistakes**

if you Are sure that api key is correct
perhaps you are using **Mobile data** this may limit of the access to map
check map access when you are connected to internet via mobile data
and check if you are allowing the location access in your device